# Multiply an integer against a fraction with rounding to whole number in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get two thirds and round to whole number.

Standard rounding:

- .6 rounds to 1
- .5 rounds to 1
- .4 rounds to 0

AwayFromZero I believe is the right option to use here. But I think my multiplication is not right because I'm getting 0 for my result.

```
int totalPoints= 71625;
int twoThirds = (int)Math.Round((double)totalPoints * (2 / 3), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer should be 47750.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `2/3` is an `int` calculation so it will return `0`, then `0 * totalPoints` equal `0`

I would use `2/3m` let the calculation result be decimal. then you can get your expectation result.

```
int totalPoints = 71625;
int twoThirds = (int)Math.Round(totalPoints * (2/3m), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: Why decimal when you’re going to round the number?

Comment: Because `decimal` have much higher precision, although it cost more memory to store the value.

Comment: And why pay the extra cost of decimal if your going to throw away all the precision rounding the number?

Answer (score 2):

While the @D-Shih answer is correct here, it is not the best you can get. Even for decimal, two thirds are not representable exactly, 2/3m is not exactly two thirds, so rounding error occurs. When you multiply the number, you multiply the error too. It is better to make the dividing as last. Let me show the difference:

```
int totalPoints = 71625;
decimal result1 = totalPoints * (2 / 3m); //47750.000000000000000000000002M
decimal result2 = (decimal)totalPoints * 2 / 3; //47750 (exactly)
double result3 = (double)totalPoints * 2 / 3; //47750 (exactly)
```

not a big deal here, as the results would be the same. But if we alter the example a bit

```
double totalPointsDouble = 71626.5d;

decimal result1 = (decimal)totalPointsDouble * (1 / 3m); //23875.499999999999999999999998M
decimal result2 = (decimal)totalPointsDouble * 1 / 3m; //23875.5M
double result3 = totalPointsDouble * 1 / 3; //23875.5

int oneThird1 = (int)Math.Round((decimal)totalPointsDouble * (1 / 3m), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
//23875
int oneThird3 = (int)Math.Round(totalPointsDouble * 1 / 3, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
//23876
```

the rounding error propagates to the result and the results differ. According to math, 23876 is correct.

Comment: The only thing that may be worth noting here is that if your input is greater than `int.MaxValue/2` then you may need to worry about overflow errors. From the looks of the variable name - `totalPoints` - I would guess that it probably will never be that big in this case.

Comment: @Chris good point. You should be aware of the ranges all the time and that is the reason why totalPoints is cast to double before it is multiplied.

Comment: True, I was forgetting that the calcs were a double so wouldn't actually overflow here!

Answer (score 0):

(2 / 3) is evaluated first because it is in parentheses. The result is 0 because this is an integer division.